# Open XML SDK Pivots - How to defer enumeration of PivotCacheRecords?

Tags: c#, pivot, openxml, openxml-sdk, pivot-table

I am trying to combine multiple excel workbooks which do not have the data source included in them. For reasons far beyond my control, I have no means to access the driving data.

Each workbook always contains exactly one pivot table, and they reliably share certain fields. Ideally, a user can choose a group of fields, and a list of workbooks, and would get one workbook with all of the combined data. It is not lost on me that is not the right way to do things, but its the hand I was dealt.

The problem;

When I address the any member of the PivotCacheRecords property of PivotTableCacheRecordsPart,  it instantly enumerates the entire list into memory. Due to certain sheets having tens of thousands of rows, and 50+ columns, this quickly consumes all available memory. Here is an example snippit.

```
  var pivotDefs = spredDoc.WorkbookPart.PivotTableCacheDefinitionParts.First();

  ...

  int i = 0;      
  var records = pivotDefs.PivotTableCacheRecordsPart.PivotCacheRecords;

  foreach(var record in records)
  {
    var fields = record.ToList();
    lastUsedRow++;
    for (int j = 0; j < fieldCount; j++)
    {
      if (reportToDefColumnLookup.ContainsKey(j) && !(fields[j] is MissingItem))
      {
        var readValue = fields[j].GetAttribute("v", "").Value;
        writer.Write(readValue + "\t");
      }
      else
      {
        writer.Write("\t");
      }
    }
    writer.WriteLine();
    i++;
    if (i % 2000 == 0)
    {
      System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("[Pivot Handler] {0} records read", i.ToString()));
    }                               
  }
```

The moment "records" is addressed (in this case, when the foreach logic calls for its enumerator - but you could replicate the behavior by calling any member property/function) the entire list is loaded into memory. The ideal solution would read each record and unload it after reading it. I tried removing the element from the list, but it did not seem to have any effect.

I have an extremely vague idea about somehow merging two pivot definitions without reproducing the tabular data, but I have no idea how to go about doing that.

I do not have a budget available for this. Any library suggestions would have to be free. I have explored EPPlus, but it does not have very good PivotTable support.

Could any one shed light on this or point me in a possible direction? Open XML documentation is notoriously difficult to find and tends to be cryptic at best.

Thanks in advance.